# About tpl files how it works

Tags: windows, codeigniter, sockets

I got a tpl file in website is it a bug.?
What if it shows 403 and I bypass it?
I am new to it can you elaborate it in detail what is tpl file and what is it used for and any other knowledge will be helpful.....

Comment: They are template files, mostly used by Adobe Photoshop. A quick google can tell you what they are used for.  Google ".tpl file"

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.